# Copy of functor and initializer_list

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, functor, initializer-list

I am a little confused about what happens when I copy functors and/or initializers. In the following code I thought I would copy/move the objects all the time but regardsless it Segfaults. I seem to be doing something wrong but haven't figured out yet, what my wrong asumptions are.
Strangely at *cppreference.com* I could not find copy or move constructor for `initializer_list` so I wonder what actually happens in these cases.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

std::initializer_list<std::function<std::string()>> getInitializer() {
  return {
    []() -> std::string {
      return "If";
    }
  };
}

int main() {
    std::function<int(std::string)> func;
    {
        auto init = getInitializer();

        func = [init](std::string text) -> int {
            std::vector<std::function<std::string()>> vec(init);

            for( auto& el : vec ) {
                std::cout << el();
            }
            std::cout << text << std::endl;
            return 5;
        };
    }

    return func(" you see this - the world is all right!");
}
```

Comment: Why not add a `using` statement at the top?

Comment: @ColeJohnson `using` for what?

Comment: @LCIDFire `using namespace std;` so you don't have to type `std::` all the time. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aewtdfs3(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @ColeJohnson It's not a good practice to use "using namespace std" everywhere, that polutes the global namespace with lots of symbols that you won't be using. LCID: nice question, it looks like the original std::functions are getting destroyed somewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have much experience with `initializer_list`s, but the standard seems to suggest the implementation of an `initializer_list` is as if its a pair of pointers to an array. The list at `getInitializer` has *automatic lifetime*, and so does the array that backs it. You end up returning a pair of pointers to an array that no longer exists.

The relevant sections of the standard are 8.5.4 [decl.init.list] items 5 and 6:

> 5.- An object of type `std::initializer_list<E>` is constructed from an initializer list as if the implementation allocated an array of *N* elements of type `E`, where *N* is the number of elements in the initializer list. Each element of that array is copy-initialized with the corresponding element of the initializer list, and the `std::initializer_list<E>` object is constructed to refer to that array. If a narrowing conversion is required to initialize any of the elements, the program is ill-formed.
>
> 6.- The lifetime of the array is the same as that of the `initializer_list` object.

---

So for your particular case, the implementation would be roughly equivalent to this:

```
std::initializer_list<std::function<std::string()>> getInitializer() {
  std::function<std::string()> __a[1] = {
    []() -> std::string {
      return "If";
    }
  };
  return std::initializer_list<std::function<std::string()>>(__a, __a+1);
}
```

Comment: I am somewhat confused. Why did they decide to implement `std::initializer_list` with a memory array? Why not go and base it upon `std::array`? To me this class is utterly broken because ordinary container usage does not work.

Comment: @LCIDFire `std::array` is not the problem here (after all an implementation is free to in fact use it). The SC chose to limit the lifetime of the objects being referred to to make the `std::initializer_list` lightweight and cheap to copy. It effectively has reference semantics, which, you're right, *is* unusual for C++. `std::initializer_list` was not intended as a container, you should return one instead.

Comment: @LCID Fire: Why dont you just use `std::array` instead?

Comment: @K-ballo When you look at how many Containers accept `std::initializer_list` arguments in their function calls you get ideas :). In the end I now use `std::vector`.

Comment: @LCID Fire: All those functions also have overloads taking a _[begin,end)_ pair of iterators, that's the way it was done back in the non-`std::initializer_list` days.

Comment: @LCIDFire `std::initializer_list` is not a container, it's not broken because it wasn't designed to be that. The problem here is you assuming and using it for something it was never meant to be used for. It's a magic feature that allows containers to be initialized conveniently, don't try to store it indefinitely, use it as a member of a class, or treat it as a first-class object meant for general applicability to any kind of code.